# How do I use multiple templates in one Vuejs project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, vue.js

I am having a bit of an issue in vuejs.
The thing is that i am trying to load more than one template in my vue project. Each component has to load his own css files.
To do that, all i could think of is to put each template css in a folder inside the static folder.
this is the index html

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

and in each component i loaded the head tag with css from the static folder

```html
<template>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title> site </title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
     
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="static/search/favicon.ico">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="static/search/favicon.ico">
      <link rel="stylesheet" id="brk-direction-bootstrap" href="static/search/css/bootstrap.css">
      
      <!-- etc etc -->
     
    </head>

    <body>
      <!-- ... -->
    </body>
  </html>
</template>
```

And that's how i solved loading different css templates in one project.
But that made the page loading have an issue, it looks completely off before the css finish loading.

[image]

I ma not sure how i can fix! calling all the css files in the index.html does not work.

Comment: Vue files can have `<style>` blocks in them; have you considered using those for the per-component styles?

Comment: but in those i can't include a file? yes let me try that

Comment: You can use `@import` to import CSS files.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work!! probably something to do with the loader configuration, i'll keep at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @puddi says, use the `<style>` tags in your component. What would seem to suit your needs best would be to use scoped style, `<style scoped>` which means the `css` you include there only applies to that component, not globally.

Depending on how adventurous you want to get, you could build your project in `Nuxt.js` (a wrapper for `vue`) which allows you to define layouts that would do exactly what you're asking.

Comment: well yeah like @puddi said! I was able to import the css file. but only one using <style src="@/assets/..."> </style> and I had to put all the css in one file and include that. I couldn't load many css files so that was my go to to fix it in a short notice!! I guess I didn't have the right loader to import many! I'll keep working on it